# Full blled background onto two side-by-side Boxes

Tags: css

I'd need to have two side-by-side Boxes, with background that is extended to full page width, but text content should be contained inside main container that is limited a specific size.

I tried the following HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <section class="left">LEFT</section>
    <section class="right">RIGHT</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here the sCSS:

```
.wrapper {
  background: lightgray;
  padding-block: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  border: dotted 1px red;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-inline: auto;
  
  section {
    padding-block: 100px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    isolation: isolate;
    
    &.left {
      background: green;
      
      &:before {
        content:"";
        display: block;
        background: green;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 500%;
        z-index: -1;
      }
    }
    
    &.right {
      background: orange;
      
      &:before {
        content:"";
        display: block;
        background: orange;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 500%;
        z-index: -1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Here a working example](https://codepen.io/ldetomi/pen/bGKjweb). Have you any suggestion to have a better solution with almost the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an extra div inside your wrapper and use a linear gradient on it:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: lightgray;
  padding-block: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, green 50%, orange 50%, orange 100%);
}

.container {
  border: dotted 1px red;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="container">
      <section class="column left">LEFT</section>
      <section class="column right">RIGHT</section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```